# JavaScript Extracting lines from csv file

Tags: javascript, csv

Please help me, I have the below code, I need to extract the start time from row 1 Col 2, and the end time Last row Col2.

Thanks

```
async function getData() {
  let fileName = document.getElementById("myFile").files[0].name;
  alert('The file "' + fileName + '" has been selected.');
  const response = await fetch("./csv/" + fileName); //fetch csv files from ./csv/folder

  const data = await response.text(); // waiting for the filename to be fetched.

  const table = data.split("\n").slice(1); // take out the headers

  table.forEach((row) => {
    const columns = row.split(","); //parse the comma separator
    const test_date = columns[1]; //select date column
    const test_time = columns[2]; //select time column
    const date_time = test_date + test_time; //concatinate date and time column
    xlabels.push(date_time); //join and display date and time in one column
    const pressure = columns[3]; //select pressure column
    yPressure.push(pressure); // display pressure column
    const temp = columns[4]; //select temp column
    yTemp.push(temp); // display temp column
    console.log(test_date, test_time, pressure, temp);
  });
}
```

Comment: the start time is in the 2nd column of row 1 of your csv?

Answer (score 0):

There are packages available for parsing csv files... Are you doing this server or client side? If you are using nodejs on the backend I've used [convert-excel-to-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-excel-to-json) in the past.. I havent done it on the frontend before but a quick google search found me [this guy](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-convert-excel-file-into-json-object-by-using-javascript-9e95532d47c5)

converting the excel file to json means its a simple matter of finding your data in the object tree :D

Comment: I am only doing it on the client side.... will check you out. Thanks

Comment: Hi Qamar, which chart can be used on the json output? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to print the items in a csv as inputs in HTML. Does this help you get your values? You can use the second js function `function createForm(csv)` to print the value you want.

```js
document.getElementById("upload").addEventListener("change", upload, false);
var out = "";

function upload(e) {
  document.getElementById('csvForm').innerHTML = "";

  var data = null;
  var file = e.target.files[0];

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsText(file);
  reader.onload = function(event) {
    var csvData = event.target.result;
    var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(csvData);

    parsedCSV.forEach(function(d, i) {
      if (i == 0) return true; // skip the header
      if (d.constructor === Array) {
        createForm(d);
      }
    });
  }
}

function createForm(csv) {

  out += '<input value="' + csv[0] + '">'; // first item in the csv
  out += '<input value="' + csv[2] + '">'; // third item in the csv

  document.getElementById('csvForm').innerHTML = out;
  out += '<br>';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>

<input id="upload" type="file">
<form id="csvForm"></form>
```

Comment: I am actually graphing the value to chart.js, but I really need to get the value of the starting time and ending time into an Input Text Element......

Comment: Hi Hisham, got your code running, I am still wondering on how to get out of the foreach loop and output only which index i want to appear on my page? Thanks

Comment: can you type out an example of the csv youre trying to get? like lets say the first row is "text1, text2, text3" and the second row is "text4, text5, text6" My code will print "text1" and "text3" in one row and "text4" and "text6" in another row

Comment: if you can type out your csv or even an exaple csv like that and say which value you want to take out, I can edit my answer and add some comments to explain how to get it done

Comment: Hi Hisham my csv file is very simple as follows:

Comment: Record,Date,UTC Time,Pressure,Temperature

Comment: I would like to get the first row of Date & Time, and last row of date and time then pass it to the html element input and display the starting date/time and ending date/time.

Comment: does your csv have multiple elements like that? for an example the 1st row has the start time and the second row has the end time yeah? does the third row show the start time again?

Comment: if thats the case in the `function createForm(csv)`, change the `[0]` and `[3]` to `[1]` and `[2]` That will print `date` and `time`